# I need to select only one value for the listitem

Tags: android

Here I select `listitem` and its color is changing for that particular item.
When I select the item for the second time this previous item should get canceled and new item color needs to be changed.

```
delivery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) ct.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v1 = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.activity_employees_list_for_pop_up, null);
            final Button ok = (Button) v1.findViewById(R.id.do_ok);
            Button cancle = (Button) v1.findViewById(R.id.do_cancle);
            final TextView empId=(TextView)v1.findViewById(R.id.employeeId);
            ok.setEnabled(false);
            listView = (ListView) v1.findViewById(R.id.employeePopUpList);
            employeePopUpAdapter = new EmployeePopUpAdapter(ct, employeeIdNameBeans);

            //enable ok button if listitem is checked
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   ok.setEnabled(true);
                   //Toast.makeText(ct, ""+employeeIdNameBeans.get(position).getEmpId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                   selectedemployeeid=employeeIdNameBeans.get(position).getEmpId();


               }
           });
```

And i need to get particular employeeid that changed the color.

And in adapter class I am just taking to values empId and empName

```
public class EmployeePopUpAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ct;
private List<EmployeeIdNameBean> employeeIdNameBeans;
private int lastPosition = -1;

public EmployeePopUpAdapter(Context ct, List<EmployeeIdNameBean> employeeIdNameBeans) {
    this.ct = ct;
    this.employeeIdNameBeans = employeeIdNameBeans;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return employeeIdNameBeans.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ct.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_for_employee_popup_window, null);
    TextView empId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.employeeId);
    TextView empName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.empFullName);

    //For animation
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ct, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.top_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
    v.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = position;

    final EmployeeIdNameBean empbean = employeeIdNameBeans.get(position);
    empId.setText(empbean.getEmpId());
    empName.setText(empbean.getEmpName());

    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: Post you adpater code as well. You need to maintain selected item position for this purpose.

Comment: @R.R.M I just added the Adapter class as well please check the code and reply. ThankYou in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this .

```
public class EmployeePopUpAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context ct;
private List<EmployeeIdNameBean> employeeIdNameBeans;
private int lastPosition = -1;
private int chooseItem = -1;

public EmployeePopUpAdapter(Context ct, List<EmployeeIdNameBean> employeeIdNameBeans) {
    this.ct = ct;
    this.employeeIdNameBeans = employeeIdNameBeans;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return employeeIdNameBeans.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public void setChooseItem(int i) {
    chooseItem = i;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ct.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_for_employee_popup_window, null);
    TextView empId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.employeeId);
    TextView empName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.empFullName);

    //For animation
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ct, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.top_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
    v.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = position;

    final EmployeeIdNameBean empbean = employeeIdNameBeans.get(position);
    empId.setText(empbean.getEmpId());
    empName.setText(empbean.getEmpName());
    // edited here ,change color
    try {
        if (chooseItem == -1) {
        } else {
            if (chooseItem == position) {
                empId.setBackgroundColor(ct.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright));
            } else {
                empId.setBackgroundColor(ct.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception E) {
    }
    return v;
}
}
```

And in your Activity code .

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            adapter.setChooseItem(i);
        }
});
```

Comment: Your code is working fine. There is one more thing i am missing. when i click on that item i need to get its empID. so then i can use it in URL

Comment: When I select particular item i need to get its EmpId.

Comment: `selectedemployeeid=employeeIdNameBeans.get(position).getEmpId();` ,Did it not get it?

Comment: ya i am already getting employee id. when i select for second time do i get that employee id or first select empId

Comment: You need to get an employee ID every time you choose

Comment: do yu mean like this. selectedemployeeid=employeeIdNameBeans.get(position).getEmpI‌​d();

Comment: ThankYou. you are very helpful

Comment: @aaron Good luck to you .

Answer (score 0):

get the selected item position and change the background color for the same, when you will click another item then refresh the list i.e. remove all selected colors and then set color for selected item.

you can also add a boolean parameter in your model class then change the value for selected item as true, in your adapter check for true value and change the background color for the same, every time you will clear the flag and refresh the list.

Comment: If I refresh the list view entire list view is gone refresh again.

Comment: refresh the list do not show it and the pass value/change the color for selected item then show the list.